# Overloading a generic extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a problem overloading an extension method.

I have two extension Methods:

Method A - For standard objects:

```
public static bool HasChanged<T>(this T obj1, T obj2, Func<T, T, bool> equalityExpression)
```

Method B - For IEnumerables:

```
public static bool HasChangedList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> obj1, IEnumerable<T> obj2, Func<T, T, bool> isEqualExpression)
```

But I would like to give them both the same names, that is currently not working, cause IEnumerables are objects aswell, so the compiler isnt able to decide whether to use the first one or the second one on an IEnumerable.

I am sure, its not possible to let first method take all object but an IEnumerable, so is there another way around?

Comment: You could check in the body of the first if it is IEnumerable and call a second private method, then you only need one.

Comment: Assigning the same names on both methods works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: You said *that is currently not working*. What does that mean? What is the error you get? or unexpected  behavior or what?

Comment: I am so sorry, I think made a mistake, it is working indeed, Visual Studios IntelliSense made me think it's not working.

Answer (score 4):

*(Not really a solution, but too long for a comment. Hopefully, one of the C# spec gurus will show up and tell us why overload resolution works like this in this particular case.)*

If

- you qualify the parameters of your equalityExpression *or* if
- the inner type of the IEnumerable can be inferred from the lambda expression,

it should work fine:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var array = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        // uses the IEnumerable overload -- prints false
        Console.WriteLine(array.HasChanged(array, (int x, int y) => x == y));

        // uses the IEnumerable overload -- prints false
        Console.WriteLine(array.HasChanged(array, (x, y) => x >= y));

        // uses the generic overload -- prints true
        Console.WriteLine(array.HasChanged(array, (x, y) => x == y));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
static class Extensions
{
    public static bool HasChanged<T>(this IEnumerable<T> obj1, IEnumerable<T> obj2, Func<T, T, bool> isEqualExpression)
    { 
        return false; 
    }
    public static bool HasChanged<T>(this T obj1, T obj2, Func<T, T, bool> equalityExpression)
    { 
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's definitely an unexpected behavior you found there.

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed, I would have expected an overload resolution ambiguity error in the last case.

Comment: If `array` is an *array* or a `List<int>`, it works as you specified. But if in any of those cases, the variable is declared as `IEnumerable<int>` instead of using `var` or `List<int>`, you get the ambiguity error. This is getting really confusing.

Comment: that's not unexpected

Comment: when you specify var the compiler assume the type is an int[] and the best overload is the generic, when you push IEnumerable<int> is ambiguous because it can use both overloads. When you specify the Func<int, int, bool> then it decide by the IEnumerable overload.

Comment: I assume that, in the last case, the generic overload is preferred, since no widening conversion `int[] -> IEnumerable<T>` is required: `int[]` can be used directly as `T`.